# Spring Ldap security to authenticate in multiple domains

Tags: spring-ldap

I have 3 ldap domains like:

```
  ldap://domain1:389/DC=xxx,DC=xxx
  ldap://domain2:389/DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx
  ldap://domain3:389/DC=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx
```

I need a mechanism if the user is not found in domain 1 it should search in domain 2 like wise. can you please guide me what is the best possible way I can do it using spring.

Answer (score 0):

You may use multiple Spring authentication-providers

```
<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider ...></ldap-authentication-provider>
    <ldap-authentication-provider ...></ldap-authentication-provider>
    <ldap-authentication-provider ...></ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```